# Session handling across multiple users and browsers

Tags: c#, session, model-view-controller

I have to implement session handling across multiple users, and multiple browsers. Each user has a unique token which I save in *HttpContext.Current.Session* variable inside the *Session__Start()* in *Global.asax.cs* method. It works perfectly fine for a single session. However, when I fire the request from two browsers, then while browsing through various pages, sometimes the method *Session_Start()* automatically gets called for the second session and it resets the session variable, resulting in a null value.

How should I handle this scenario?

**Edit 1:** 
What are the scenarios where the session may time out? Eg: switching between HTTPGet/HttpPost, or making Ajax calls?

I also read this link: 
[Does Session timeout reset on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370110/does-session-timeout-reset-on-every-request)

Is this something which I should be keeping in mind? My code has 2 GET and 1 POST request, and the session variable becomes NULL in the POST method for the second browser session.

Comment: Define "two browsers".

Comment: I tried from **firefox** and **chrome** because I wanted to test for multiple simultaneously active sessions. However I am looking for multiple sessions across users, who are not logged in but just using the web application normally.

Comment: Each browser is going to handle session on its own. Within a browser, session is implementation specific, but generally speaking session is shared among tabs (excluding "private browsing sessions"). This is due to session being tracked via a cookie. Cookies are tied to (remote) domains, not browser tabs/windows, so when you open a new tab to the same site, the same cookie gets submitted to the remote server.

Comment: I understand that different tabs within the same browser share cookies, but what about different browser windows, eg: 1 Firefox window, and 1 Chrome window?

Comment: I figured out the reason. The sessionState mode in web.config file was set to "InProc", whereas it should be set as "StateServer". When I made the necessary change, then it worked like a charm.

ASP.net state service should also be started from services.msc for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason. The sessionState mode in web.config file was set to "InProc", whereas it should be set as "StateServer". When I made the necessary change, then it worked like a charm.

ASP.net state service should also be started from services.msc for this to work.

Comment: There are some additional points to note:
Adding/removing the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie will also reset the session.